# Storing data externally

Tags: c#, io

Im looking for a way to store the data that my program generates (small lists) remotely instead of locally. I currently store data in .txt files.

The problem is that i cannot have a unified .txt file for all users.

The idea i got so far is to write a small api in php which has a mysql backend. I just wanted to ask here what you think would be the easiest/fastest way of accomplishing this sort of cloud data storage?

Comment: This is a very broad question. Try to limit the scope: Are you asking about how to do the PHP/MySQL solution or about how to communicate to it from your C# program? What specific problems are you facing? Please consider dividing your question into several questions if you need to.

Comment: Sorry if i am being unclear, i am trying to ask what options i have if i want to store data that can be accessed by all users of the program

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have basically two options :

- Storing directly in a Database
- Calling a web service and passing the data, then handling the storing in the service logic

What to choose depends on the context and on the requirements, however i would prefer the second option, because in this way you decouple the two things ...

Comment: Are there any free solutions out there that let you store data on a web service? Or should i write my php script to store in a mysql db for me?

Answer (score 0):

Suggested way is using **[WCF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/netframework/aa663324.aspx)** (Windows Communication Foundation) to communicate to a central system that store your data. there are very good solutions for your question in this platform.

> WCF is a part of the .NET Framework that provides a unified programming model for rapidly building service-oriented applications that communicate across the web and the enterprise.